# Can no longer edit my contacts in iOS 5

Tags: ios, icloud, contacts

I just updated to iOS 5 on my iPhone 4, and now I can not edit my contacts. Where "edit" use to be is no longer there. If I type a new number on the keypad and hit add to existing contact, I can edit from there, but there is no "done" or "save". Not sure what to do.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be a bug. I ran into this same problem over the weekend when I was trying to add a new contact I had received over SMS. It seems that depending on how you get to the contact screen, the "Done" button may not be there. If you open the Contacts app (instead of getting to your contacts from the Phone app), you should get a contact screen that has the save button. Hope this helps.

Comment: I can't get into the edit screen nomatter what I try. Are there any workarounds that you know of? Even going in through recent calls or messages doesn't help.

Comment: I don't know of any workarounds. The Contacts app is working fine for me. It allows me to get to the screen where I can edit a contact and it displays the Save button.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issue, the edit button mysteriously disappeared!

**I was able to resolve my issue by going into `settings` -> `iCloud` and switching `Contacts` to ON.**

[image]

Comment: The iCloud on procedure also asks for a "merge". Will merge a users contacts with the home computer's contacts?